# how to match exact word in regex

Tags: regex

I have a string below, I would like to extract number (12,000) from TOTAL but not from CLIENT SUB-TOTAL

```
CLIENT SUB-TOTAL :       12,000                                    12,000
                                                          ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
                                                  TOTAL :       12,000                                    12,000
```

I have tried with the following regex, but it still matches 2 group.

```
(?:TOTAL :       )([0-9]+[,]+[0-9]+)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Just a quick and easy way, you could add a space at the front ` (?:TOTAL :       )([0-9]+[,]+[0-9]+)`

Comment: Would you try: `(?<!SUB-)(?:TOTAL\s*:\s*)([0-9]+[,]+[0-9]+)`  [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rYvKJf/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing a negative assertion that `TOTAL` isn't preceded by a dash. Something like the following would work:

- [`(?<!-)TOTAL[^\d]+([\d,]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/lE32AF/1/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the non capture group `(?:` in the pattern that you tried as you are matching the text only.

Also not that you don't need the square brackets here `[,]+` and due to the `+` it could possibly also match `,,,,`

What you might do is assert a whitespace boundary to the left if a negative lookbehind is supported, and instead of hardcoding the exact amount of spaces, match  1 or more whitespace chars without a newline using `[^\S\r\n]+`

```
(?<!\S)TOTAL[^\S\r\n]+:[^\S\r\n]+([0-9]+,[0-9]+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qTniuy/1)